# Properly Use distinct with count on data from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 different tables with similar data on them, One is a table of part numbers where each Part number is unique and the table describes the part number, and the other table is a collection of quotes and can have a part number recur multiple times on the table.

Example:

```
PN Table

partNum|someOther
-------|---------
1234   | data
12345  | more data
1234-0 | no data

Quotes Table

partNum|QuoteNum
-------|---------
1234   | 1
12345  | 2
1234   | 3
1234   | 4
1234   | 5
12345  | 6
1234-0 | 7
```

I have this statement that I am working with

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT p.partNum AS pn,
    COUNT(q.partNum) AS prevQuotes
FROM
    PN p
LEFT JOIN
    Quotes q ON p.partNum = q.partNum
WHERE
    stripped_pn LIKE '123%'
```

I would have expected the statement to return multiple results with the count of occurrences from the Quote table, except I only get one result with a count.
What modification would I have to make to get the PN with the number of times it occurred in the Quotes Table?

Comment: `GROUP BY` is typically used for aggregation (COUNT, SUM, etc...), not `DISTINCT`; `DISTINCT` is used to return unique result rows from the query, aggregation without a `GROUP BY` only ever yields a single row.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised your statement works at all. The aggregate function COUT requires a GROUP BY like so:

```
SELECT 
    p.partNum AS pn,
    COUNT(q.partNum) AS prevQuotes
FROM
    PN p
LEFT JOIN
    Quotes q ON p.partNum = q.partNum
WHERE
    stripped_pn LIKE '123%'
GROUP BY p.partNum
```